# Getting duplicates with information

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

**EDIT author:** this question is wrongly described. [Here's the rephrased one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991446/getting-duplicates-with-additional-information).

---

I've inherited a database and I'm having trouble constructing a working SQL query.

Suppose this is the data:

```
[Table]

| Id    | DisplayId     | Sequence  | Type      | Description   |
|----   |-----------    |---------- |-----------| -----------   |
| 1     | 12345         | 0         | 16        | Random        |
| 2     | 12345         | 0         | 2         | Random 2      |
| 3     | AB123         | 0         | 1         | Random 3      |
| 4     | 12345         | 1         | 16        | Random 4      |
| 5     | 12345         | 1         | 2         | Random 5      |
| 6     | XX45          | 0         | 5         | Random 6      |
| 7     | 12345         | 2         | 16        | Random 7      |
| 8     | 12345         | 2         | 2         | Random 8      |
| 9     | XX45          | 1         | 5         | Random 9      |
| 10    | XX45          | 2         | 5         | Random 10     |
| 11    | XX45          | 2         | 12        | Random 11     |
| 12    | 12345         | 3         | 16        | Random 12     |


[Type]

| Id    | State     |
|----   |-----------|
| 1     | 'ABC'     |
| 2     | '456'     |
| 5     | 'XYZ'     |
| 12    | 'XYZ'     |
| 16    | '456'     |
```

The `Type` column is a foreign key referencing the `Type` table.
Now I need to select rows that are duplicates when **only** comparing `DisplayId` and `Type.State`, and then only display the highest `Sequence` for each `DisplayId / Type.State` set. Also, the `Id` column should be used to join additional data (e.g. `OtherTable.Title`).

So for the data shown above, this would be the expected result:

```
| Id    | DisplayId     | Sequence  | Type      | Description   | OtherTable.Title  |
|----   |-----------    |---------- |-----------|-------------  |------------------ |
| 8     | 12345         | 2         | 2         | Random 8      | Title 8           |
| 10    | XX45          | 2         | 5         | Random 10     | Title 10          |
| 11    | XX45          | 2         | 12        | Random 11     | Title 11          |
| 12    | 12345         | 3         | 16        | Random 12     | Title 12          |
```

I managed to get the comparison and highest sequence selection working to get a distinct list of `DisplayId/Type` having duplicates, but as soon as I insert the `Id` column again to show additional data all is messed up...

```
SELECT
    P.DisplayId, P.Type
FROM
    Table P
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DisplayId, MAX(Sequence) AS Seq FROM Table GROUP BY DisplayId) HighSeq ON P.DisplayId = HighSeq.DisplayId AND P.Sequence = HighSeq.Seq
GROUP BY
    P.DisplayId, P.Type
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

I'm eager to learn your insights...

Answer (score 0):

Use Row Number

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DisplayId,[Sequence] ORDER BY DisplayId,[Sequence]),
        Id ,
        DisplayId,
        [Sequence],
        [Type],
        [Description]
        FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN YourTable2 YT2
            ON CTE.ID = YT2.ID
        WHERE CTE.RN > 1
```

You can join other tables with CTE just like how you are doing it for normal tables

Comment: For the sample data your solution is returning rows 2 , 5 , 8  and 11... I need 8, 10, 11 and 12

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT T.*, OT.Title 
    FROM (
    SELECT M.*, Type.State, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DisplayId, M.[Type], Type.State ORDER BY Sequence DESC ),
        CNT = COUNT(M.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY DisplayId, Type.State )
    FROM MyTable M
    INNER JOIN Type Type ON M.[Type] = Type.Id
) T 
INNER JOIN OtherTable OT ON T.Id = OT.ID
WHERE 
    T.RN = 1
    AND T.CNT > 1
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: It's not filtering out non-duplicates...

Comment: i made an update.

Comment: It's not catching row 11

Comment: because it is not duplicate, what is your duplicate criteria?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, made a little mistake in my expected results table.

Comment: Duplicate criteria updated in the OP: Table.DisplayId  +   Type.State (Type column is a foreign key as well)

Comment: I added Type table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162022/discussion-between-propaganistas-and-serkan-arslan).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select ID,a.displayid,sequence,type, table2.Title from
(select ID,displayid,sequence,type, Row_number() over (partition by displayid,Type order by sequence desc) rn
from table1) a inner join table2 on a.id = table2.id and a.rn=1
```

Comment: Row 3 is included in the results

Answer (score 0):

This returns your expected results except for type 12 as it is not a duplicate.

```
;
WITH base
AS (SELECT
  DisplayId,
  [sequence],
  [Type],
  [Description],
  [State],
  High_sequence = MAX([Sequence]) OVER (ORDER BY [type]),
  dups = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY [type])
FROM [Type] TY
INNER JOIN [Table] TBL
  ON TY.Id = TBL.Type)
SELECT
  t.Id,
  t.DisplayId,
  t.[sequence],
  t.[Type],
  t.[Description],
  [State]
FROM base b
INNER JOIN [Table] t
  ON b.Sequence = t.Sequence
  AND b.Type = t.Type
  AND b.DisplayId = t.DisplayId
WHERE b.[sequence] = High_sequence
AND dups > 1;
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't seem to work on my data..