# Getting duplicates with additional information

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I've inherited a database and I'm having trouble constructing a working SQL query.

Suppose this is the data:

```
[Products]

| Id    | DisplayId     | Version   | Company   | Description   |
|----   |-----------    |---------- |-----------| -----------   |
| 1     | 12345         | 0         | 16        | Random        |
| 2     | 12345         | 0         | 2         | Random 2      |
| 3     | AB123         | 0         | 1         | Random 3      |
| 4     | 12345         | 1         | 16        | Random 4      |
| 5     | 12345         | 1         | 2         | Random 5      |
| 6     | AB123         | 0         | 5         | Random 6      |
| 7     | 12345         | 2         | 16        | Random 7      |
| 8     | XX45          | 0         | 5         | Random 8      |
| 9     | XX45          | 0         | 7         | Random 9      |
| 10    | XX45          | 1         | 5         | Random 10     |
| 11    | XX45          | 1         | 7         | Random 11     |


[Companies]

| Id    | Code      |
|----   |-----------|
| 1     | 'ABC'     |
| 2     | '456'     |
| 5     | 'XYZ'     |
| 7     | 'XYZ'     |
| 16    | '456'     |
```

The `Version`column is a version number. Higher numbers indicate more recent versions.
The `Company` column is a foreign key referencing the `Companies` table on the `Id` column.
There's another table called `ProductData` with a `ProductId` column referencing `Products.Id`.

Now I need to find duplicates based on the `DisplayId` and the corresponding `Companies.Code`. The `ProductData` table should be joined to show a title (`ProductData.Title`), and only the most recent ones should be included in the results. So the expected results are:

```
| Id    | DisplayId     | Version   | Company   | Description   | ProductData.Title |
|----   |-----------    |---------- |-----------|-------------  |------------------ |
| 5     | 12345         | 1         | 2         | Random 2      | Title 2           |
| 7     | 12345         | 2         | 16        | Random 7      | Title 7           |
| 10    | XX45          | 1         | 5         | Random 10     | Title 10          |
| 11    | XX45          | 1         | 7         | Random 11     | Title 11          |
```

- because XX45 has 2 "entries": one with Company 5 and one with Company 7, but both companies share the same code.
- because 12345 has 2 "entries": one with Company 2 and one with Company 16, but both companies share the same code. Note that the most recent version of both differs (version 2 for company 16's entry and version 1 for company 2's entry)
- ABC123 should not be included as its 2 entries have different company codes.

I'm eager to learn your insights...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.ID,displayid,version,company,productdata.title
FROM 
(select A.ID,a.displayid,version,a.company,rn,a.code, COUNT(displayid)  over (partition by displayid,code) cnt from
(select Prod.ID,displayid,version,company,Companies.code, Row_number() over (partition by displayid,company order by version desc) rn
from Prod inner join Companies on Prod.Company = Companies.id) a  
where a.rn=1) b inner join productdata on b.id = productdata.id  where cnt =2
```

Comment: At first sight this one seems to be working! Let me test some more and accept your answer if all seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, you can use *CTE* to find all the duplicated rows from your table, then you can just use SELECT from CTE and even add more manipulations.

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT Id,DisplayId,Version,Company,Description,ProductData.Title
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY DisplayId, Company ORDER BY p.Id DESC)
   FROM dbo.YourTable1
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Comment: you need to partition by company also

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev you right, i edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't implement the Company.Code duplication criteria? Only rows with duplicate Company.Code + DisplayId should be included. Company ID can be different; the check should be performed on Company.Code

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, you just need to `JOIN` the tables:

```
  SELECT 
    p.Id, p.DisplayId, p.Version, p.Company, d.Title
  FROM Products AS p
  INNER JOIN Companies AS c ON p.Company = c.Id
  INNER JOIN ProductData AS d ON d.ProductId = p.Id;
```

But if you want the latest one, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
    p.Id, p.DisplayId, p.Version, p.Company, d.Title,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.DisplayId,p.Company ORDER BY p.Id DESC) AS RN
  FROM Products AS p
  INNER JOIN Companies AS c ON p.Company = c.Id
  INNER JOIN ProductData AS d ON d.ProductId = p.Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

[sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed35ab/4)

```
| Id | DisplayId | Version | Company |    Title |
|----|-----------|---------|---------|----------|
|  5 |     12345 |       1 |       2 |  Title 5 |
|  7 |     12345 |       2 |      16 |  Title 7 |
| 10 |      XX45 |       1 |       5 | Title 10 |
| 11 |      XX45 |       1 |       7 | Title 11 |
```

Comment: You didn't implement the `Company.Code` duplication criteria? Only rows with duplicate Company.Code + DisplayId should be included

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get the current version and then you see how many times the DisplayID + Code show-up. Then based on that you can select only the ones that have a count greater than one. You can then INNER JOIN ProductData on the final query to get the Title.

```
WITH
MaxVersion AS --Get the current versions
(
    SELECT
        MAX(Version) AS Version,
        DisplayID,
        Company
    FROM
        #TmpProducts
    GROUP BY
        DisplayID,
        Company
)
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        p.DisplayID,
        c.Code,
        COUNT(*) AS RowCounter
    FROM
        #TmpProducts p
    INNER JOIN
        #TmpCompanies c
        ON
            c.ID = p.Company
    INNER JOIN
        MaxVersion mv
        ON
            mv.DisplayID = p.DisplayID
        AND mv.Version = p.Version
        AND mv.Company = p.Company
    GROUP BY
        p.DisplayID,
        c.Code
)

SELECT 
    p.*
FROM
    #TmpProducts p
INNER JOIN
    CTE c
    ON
        c.DisplayID = p.DisplayID
INNER JOIN
    MaxVersion mv
    ON
        mv.DisplayID = p.DisplayID
    AND mv.Company = p.Company
    AND mv.Version = p.Version
WHERE
    c.RowCounter > 1
```